# No SQL result on inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

- *failures*; with fields FailureId, Cause, Effect, Postalcode, Housenumber
- *coordinates*; with fields Postalcode, Housenumber, X, Y

The table *coordinates* contains all the postalcodes and housenumber combinations that are present in the table *failures*.

I would like to do a query on both tables and get back all fields from the table *failures* and only the matching X and Y fields from the table *coordinates* (matching on postalcode and housenumber).

For this I wrote an inner join SQL statement for a query in MS Access like

```
SELECT failures.*, coordinates.X, coordinates.Y
FROM failures 
INNER JOIN coordinates 
ON failures.Postalcode = coordinates.Postalcode 
AND failures.Housenumber = coordinates.Housenumber;
```

Example data table *Failures*:

```
FailureId   DateReported    Postalcode      Housenumber
1           4-1-2018        7711 AH         62
2           20-2-2018       8326 AC         52
```

Example data table *Coordinates*:

```
Id  Postalcode  Housenumber     x           y
1   7711 AH         62          216050,15   510800,37
2   7711 AH         64          216046,74   510809,37
3   7711 AH         66          216042,18   510821,34
4   8326 AC         52          196171,06   522611,87
```

What I would like as a result is:

```
FailureId   DateReported    Postalcode  Housenumber      X             Y
1           4-1-2018        7711 AH         64        216046,74     510809,37
2           20-2-2018       8326 AC         52        196171,06     522611,87
```

My query doesn't return any record though, only the header row with the field names. So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: Add some sample table data for the two tables and also the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: Check your data. Do the post codes in one table include spaces, but not in the other table? Are the columns the same data types? Are both tables actually populated with data? What tests have you done to PROVE your assumption that you should get matching records?

Comment: @MatBailie I have checked (and double checked) the data, but I can't find any differences in both the field definitions and the data itself (extra spaces etc)...

Comment: Show us the table definitions. Show us the results of your sample data, plus the length of each string value (using sql to calculate it, not using your eyes and then counting on your fingers and toes). Your query is fine, you're getting results from other queries, your data almost certainly doesn't match.  The most common issue being white space at the end of a string.

Comment: You can also compare string with UNION as it will remove duplicates. This should return only one row, according to your sample data...  `SELECT Postalcode FROM failures WHERE id = 1 UNION SELECT Postalcode FROM coordinates WHERE id = 1`

Comment: So, any news then?

Comment: I did a test with a smaller dataset I created myself, and indeed the query should work. I am struggling however how to post all the field properties efficently...

Comment: @MatBailie It turns out that the input mask was the problem... It was set to "0000\ >LL;;_" for the 'failures' table and not set for the 'coordinates' table. So the first table appeared(!) to have a space between the numbers and the characters, but actually didn't (when I removed the input mask)... So thank you for pointing out the search direction!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the input mask on the 'Postalcode' field (in the 'failures' table) was the problem. It was set to "0000\ >LL;;_" and afterwards set for the 'coordinates' table when it already contained data. So the data in the 'failures' table appeared to have a space between the numbers and the characters in the postalcode (but didn't), and the data in the 'coordinates' table did.

Thank you for your questions and search directions!